# Book where flying vulcren creatures attack a ship and the female main character needs the antler of a white stag

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book and I forgot the name of it but all I remember is that there is a girl as the main character. She's on a ship with other people and the ship gets attacked by vulcren which are a flying horror creature. I also remember that there is a white stag and she needs the antler to turn it into a necklace to master her powers. She is able to use her powers for light.

Comment: Hello Eliza. Do you remember when you read this book? Where / in which language? Please take a look at [this checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/19561) and [edit] your question if you remember any additional details.

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 8):

Could it be [Shadow and Bone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_and_Bone) by Leigh Bardugo?  It's got monsters named volcra, ships, and an antler necklace.

> Alina Starkov is a teenaged orphan, a citizen of the Kingdom of Ravka.
>   She grew up with Malyen Oretsev at a orphanage in Keramzin, which is
>   sponsored by a wealthy patron. As the story begins they are marching
>   to the Unsea (also referred to as the Fold), a perpetually dark,
>   barren, strip of land cutting most of Ravka off from the sea. Periodic
>   expeditions are sent across to take goods to the sea and bring back
>   imports. The crossing is dangerous because the Unsea is inhabited by
>   monsters named volcra. Early in their crossing, the volcra attack,
>   and, while saving Mal, Alina displays an extraordinary Grisha talent.
>   The Grisha are people with the ability to manipulate the elements to
>   use as weapons, e.g. to call fire, to summon wind, to stop hearts.
>   Alina can summon light.